# Tooltipster close all before opening a new one, click/hover combination

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltipster

I'm using [tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) to build some call-outs. I've some on click, some on hover.

JS:

```
var instances = $.tooltipster.instances();

$('.mgu-click').tooltipster({
  functionBefore: function(instance, helper) {
    $.each(instances, function(i, instance) {
      instance.close();
    });
  },
  contentCloning: true,
  trigger: 'click',
  'maxWidth': 280,
  'minHeight': 280,
  animation: 'grow',
  interactive: true,
  arrow: false,
  distance: -10,
  contentAsHTML: true,
  theme: 'tooltipster-shadow'
});
$('.mgu-hover').tooltipster({
  functionBefore: function(instance, helper) {
    $.each(instances, function(i, instance) {
      instance.close();
    });
  },
  contentCloning: true,
  trigger: (browser.hasTouchEvents()) ? 'click' : 'hover',
  'maxWidth': 280,
  'minHeight': 280,
  animation: 'grow',
  interactive: true,
  arrow: false,
  distance: -10,
  contentAsHTML: true,
  theme: 'tooltipster-shadow'
});
```

If you click or move to a tooltipster-btn all other should close before the selected open. The functionBefore work fine with the trigger: click. But if i call the one with trigger hover, all other dont close.

thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you need to call the `$.tooltipster.instances()` method within the `functionBefore` function for a reference to the latest instances:

```
functionBefore: function(instance, helper){
  $.each($.tooltipster.instances(), function(i, instance){
    instance.close();
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I've customed the open/close actions with: click (element) to open tooltip and then click on a button within the tooltip html to close it, so the above code works perfectly to ensure that only one is open at a time.